# How can i correctly use mat-form-field to get the input values (UPDATED)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

[link referring the error with textbox above the floating line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUMBh.png) I'm new to mat-form-fields. im trying to explore it by using mat-form-field to my form as a test. I'm getting a text box border when using the mat library. which is unusual

i tried using mat-form-field followed by input tag and i still get the border coming up

```
<div fxFlex="120px">
     <label class="studentName">Student Name</label><sup class="red- 
             color">*</sup>
</div>
        <!--<div fxFlex="calc(100% - 135px)" fxLayout="column" >-->
<mat-form-field class="fullWidth">
      <input matInput formControlName="studentName"
             id="studentName"
             name="studentName"
             required>
            <!--<app-error-message [control]="form.controls.studentName"></app-error-message>-->
 </mat-form-field>
```

i shouldn't get the text box coming up, which turns to be a border .

I'm expecting something like this : https://stackblitz.com/angular/mnrjgnnqmqv?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts

My Css file follows:

```
.alignment .mat-form-field-outline-start,
.alignment .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: mat-form-field's appearanace is legacy by default (borderless). You must a have css that overrides this in either your global style.css file or the components style definitions. Can you also post your style files.

Comment: can you create  a stackblitz ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @talhature, i have added the css. please check

Comment: oops that's tricky @HUSSAIN. i added that in stackblitz and its fine there. but isn't working in mine. i'm getting it with a text box above the floating line. what could be the issue?

Comment: this is the Stackblitz working example(https://mnrjgnnqmqv.angular.stackblitz.io) but it doesn't work in my local IDE (Webstorm) i still get a text-box border over the floating line

Comment: @HUSSAIN. I have update the question with the error image.

Comment: @krishnaram i saw the error and i guess some of your css is overriding the all input tags so please check your css files and see if you are adding any borders to input tag , or it can be that you are using bootstrap class, form-control which applies border to your input tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if you couldn't find the css which is overriding your input add this css

```
mat-form-field.mat-form-field input {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: you can also try to remove !important if it works without it

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56143850/how-to-dynamically-change-the-value-of-placeholder-upon-the-selected-values-in-t). Can you answer this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field class="fullWidth">
    <input matInput placeholder="Student Name" [(ngModel)]='variableName' required>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort @kashif, but the error still survives !!

Comment: what actually error showing ?? share with me (error)

Comment: im getting a text box above the floating line