# how to dynamically change the value of placeholder upon the selected values in the drop down?

Tags: angular, select, placeholder

I have a drop down containing: father, mother and guardian. Followed by an input text-box with no placeholder on it. I wanted the placeholder of the text-box to update dynamically according to the value selected

I tried using assigning a string to placeholder property in the ts file section. but it could only choose that particular value. i wanted it to choose with an *ngIf

`this is the select drop-down`

```
<mat-select placeholder="Relation to Student"formControlName="relationType">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let relation of relationType" [value]="relation">
         {{ relation }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

`this is the html input`

```
<input matInput placeholder="{{related}} " formControlName="fatherFullName" required>
```

`this is the ts and i know this isn't how it works. i'm sure of adding an "if" but i'm not sure of how to do it`

```
related = ' Father's full name';
```

I'm expecting a result where if father is selected in the select drop-down, the placeholder in the input text-box should be Father's full name.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: if you can create a stackblitz then it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> hi, i guess this is what you asking for:

in your html

```
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="{{str}}" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="changeData" (ngModelChange)="test()" name="dropBox">
      <mat-option value="relation1">relation1</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="relation2">relation2</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="relation3">relation3</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

now in your ts file

```
str =  '';
changeData:any ;
test(){
  console.log("rest");
  this.str = this.changeData;
}
```

Comment: here is the working example i created on stackblitz 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wu3mrc

Comment: thanks for the effort @HUSSAIN, but it still doesn't work. I have updated my stackblits (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sefgye?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) and i think you have provided a wrong stackblits link. Please check and update.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wu3mrc?embed=1&file=main.ts
 here is the embed url  but the upper url also works fine for me even when i am not sign in

Comment: @krishnaram i updated the code of this answer as well, please replace (ngchange) to (change) in your select box

Comment: it is still not working . Can you please send me the updated link for the stackblitz that you created?

Comment: you can find this project on my stackblitz profile
 https://stackblitz.com/@maksof-Hussain
 here is the url

Comment: i wanted the values to be changed with the select drop down and not with a button.

Comment: @krishnaram i changed my code according to your condition, if you want custom text just add your condition according to value selected by user hope.